# PowerShell - Convert Property Names from Pascal Case to Upper Case With Underscores

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

Let's say I have an object like this:

```
$test = @{
          ThisIsTheFirstColumn = "ValueInFirstColumn"; 
          ThisIsTheSecondColumn = "ValueInSecondColumn"
         }
```

and I want to end up with:

```
$test = @{
          THIS_IS_THE_FIRST_COLUMN = "ValueInFirstColumn"; 
          THIS_IS_THE_SECOND_COLUMN = "ValueInSecondColumn"
         }
```

without manually coding the new column names.

This shows me the values I want:

```
$test.PsObject.Properties | where-object { $_.Name -eq "Keys" } | select -expand value | foreach{ ($_.substring(0,1).toupper() + $_.substring(1) -creplace '[^\p{Ll}\s]', '_$&').Trim("_").ToUpper()} | Out-Host
```

which results in:

```
THIS_IS_THE_FIRST_COLUMN
THIS_IS_THE_SECOND_COLUMN
```

but now I can't seem to figure out how to assign these new values back to the object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can modify hashtable `$test` in place as follows:

```
foreach($key in @($test.Keys)) { # !! @(...) is required - see below.
  $value = $test[$key] # save value
  $test.Remove($key)   # remove old entry
  # Recreate the entry with the transformed name.
  $test[($key -creplace '(?<!^)\p{Lu}', '_$&').ToUpper()] = $value
}
```

`@($test.Keys)` creates an array from the existing hashtable keys; `@(...)` ensures that the key collection is copied to a *static array*, because using the `.Keys` property directly in a loop that modifies the same hashtable would break.

The loop body saves the value for the input key at hand and then removes the entry under its old name.<sup>[1]</sup>

The entry is then recreated under its new key name using the desired name transformation:

`$key -creplace '(?<!^)\p{Lu}` matches every uppercase letter (`\p{Lu}`) in a given key, except at the start of the string (`(?<!^)`), and replaces it with `_` followed by that letter (`_$&`); converting the result to uppercase (`.ToUpper()`) yields the desired name.

---

<sup>[1] Removing the old entry *before* adding the renamed one avoids problems with *single-word* names such as `Simplest`, whose transformed name, `SIMPLEST`, is considered the *same* name due to the case-insensitivity of hasthables in PowerShell. Thus, assigning a value to entry `SIMPLEST` while entry `Simplest` still exists actually targets the *existing* entry, and the subsequent `$test.Remove($key)` would then simply remove that entry, without having added a new one.

Tip of the hat to [JosefZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3439404/josefz) for pointing out the problem.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

[*I wonder if it is possible to do it in place on the original object?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53822910/powershell-convert-property-names-from-pascal-case-to-upper-case-with-undersco#comment94494975_53823075)

`($test.PsObject.Properties|Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "Keys"}).IsSettable` says `False`. Hence, you need do it in two steps as follows:

```
$test = @{
          ThisIsTheFirstColumn = "ValueInFirstColumn"; 
          ThisIsTheSecondColumn = "ValueInSecondColumn"
         }
$auxarr = $test.PsObject.Properties |
  Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "Keys" } | 
    select -ExpandProperty value 
$auxarr | ForEach-Object { 
    $aux = ($_.substring(0,1).toupper() + 
    $_.substring(1) -creplace '[^\p{Ll}\s]', '_$&').Trim("_").ToUpper()
    $test.ADD( $aux, $test.$_)
    $test.Remove( $_)
}
$test
```

Two-step approach is necessary as an attempt to perform `REMOVE` and `ADD` methods in the only pipeline leads to the following error:

> ```
> select : Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
> ```

**Edit**. Unfortunately, the above solution would fail in case of an one-word *Pascal Case* key, e.g. for `Simplest = "ValueInSimplest"`. Here's the improved script:

```
$test = @{
          ThisIsTheFirstColumn = "ValueInFirstColumn"; 
          ThisIsTheSecondColumn = "ValueInSecondColumn"
          Simplest = "ValueInSimplest" # the simplest (one word) PascalCase
         }
$auxarr = $test.PsObject.Properties |
  Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "Keys" } | 
    select -ExpandProperty value
$auxarr | ForEach-Object { 
    $aux = ($_.substring(0,1).toupper() + 
      $_.substring(1) -creplace '[^\p{Ll}\s]', '_$&').Trim("_").ToUpper()
    $newvalue =  $test.$_
    $test.Remove( $_)
    $test.Add( $aux, $newvalue)
}
$test
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work.  I ended up putting stuff in a new hashtable, though.

```
$test = @{
          ThisIsTheFirstColumn = "ValueInFirstColumn"; 
          ThisIsTheSecondColumn = "ValueInSecondColumn"
         }  
$test2=@{}
$test.PsObject.Properties | 
    where-object { $_.Name -eq "Keys" } | 
    select -expand value | foreach{ $originalPropertyName=$_
                                    $prop=($_.substring(0,1).toupper() + $_.substring(1) -creplace '[^\p{Ll}\s]', '_$&').Trim("_").ToUpper()
                                    $test2.Add($prop,$test[$originalPropertyName])
                                  } 
$test2
```

Comment: That works. I wonder if it is possible to do it in place on the original object?